# calling a class method from an object that is accessed via an array index

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

Rookie question I'm sure. Be gentle. (Or not, it won't kill me).

Maybe the answer is already posted and I just haven't recognized it in my search, but here goes:

I have a class that defines a method. I've created a couple instances of that class and saved them in an array. When I attempt to access the instance method, as defined in the class, I get an error "Cannot read property'. If I assign the array indexed object to a variable and make the call, it does not throw an error but also does not seem to work as expected. That is, in my loop it seems to assign the method only for the last iteration.  The code may help, embarrassing though it may be:

```
class Track {

        constructor(path,docroot) {
                this.path = path;
                this.docroot = docroot;
        }

        urlpath() {
                var x = this.docroot.length;
                return this.path.substring(x);
        };

        createWave(id) {
                var url = this.urlpath();

                var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
                        container: '#' + id,
                        waveColor: 'violet',
                        progressColor: 'purple'
                });

                wavesurfer.load(url);
                return wavesurfer;
        }

}

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        tracks[i] = new Track(audiofiles[i],docroot);
        waves[i]  = tracks[i].createWave("wave-container-" + i);

        var w = waves[i];

        var playpausebtn       = document.createElement('BUTTON');
        playpausebtn.innerHTML = "Play / Pause";
        playpausebtn.id        = "playpause";
        document.getElementById('wave-container-' + i).appendChild(playpausebtn);
        document.getElementById('playpause').onclick = function() { w.playPause(); };
}
```

For those familiar with it, wavesurfer.js defines the playPause method for the wavesurfer object, returned by createWave() in my class method. If I call it with `w.playPause` as above, it works - but only for one of the two instances. If I forego the var w = waves[i] assignment and simply try to set the onclick action to waves[i].playPause()` I get the error mentioned.

I don't know if this is enough to go on, but would appreciate any guidance or hints.

Comment: Where is audiofiles coming from? not seeing it being declared anywhere

Comment: var audiofiles = [
        '/home4/mifydnu/sandbox/audio/test/disco-1.mp3',
        '/home4/mifydnu/sandbox/audio/test/disco-1.mp3'
];

Comment: The error 'Cannot read property' is thrown when you're trying to access which method? createWave? I would paste the whole code to https://jsfiddle.net so that we can see what error you're having more easily

Comment: You are creating multiple buttons that all have the same `id`. The last line in your for loop keeps overwriting the first button's `onclick`. Remove the id assignment from the loop and just use `playpausebtn.onclick = ...`

Comment: Here's example code that avoids creating multiple `onclick` functions: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/naue26t9/

Comment: @chrisg exactly right. Dangers of cut and paste. That corrected, now both buttons work, though they both start/stop the same track rather than the track that (I think) they are assigned to manage. Will try to post all to jsfiddle.net for clarification. Thanks!

Comment: @mifydnu My example code shows how to make sure the buttons behave properly.  A quick fix is to use `let` instead of `var` for the click handler related variables, however using a single function is better practice.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k53uq8h6/4/    I think I've posted my code. Sorry folks - this is all a bit new to me.

Comment: @chrisg Just trying to figure out how to mark this as the answer (awesome) and to understand how it actually works. :-)  You solved in 5 minutes what I've spent two days on. Much appreciated.

Comment: @mifydnu You're welcome, but I deliberately didn't post an answer because it's what I regard as cheap points mining. SO isn't so much about solving an individual's problem as it is about creating a repository of useful questions and answers. This Q is unlikely to ever help anyone else, mostly because somebody in a similar situation will not find it. It's also a duplicate many times over, since assigning the same `id` multiple times is a classic beginner's mistake (no offense).

Comment: @chrisg Understood. I am still mystified as to why waves[i].playPause (even with the button id corrected) did not work while tracks[i].playPause() did. I would seem to be calling the same function but at one level higher an abstraction. Perhaps because waves[i] is created as an instance of class Track and doesn't have direct access to the underlying object method for the wavesurfer object? In any case, thanks for chipping away one more burr of ignorance!